# azure sql failover duration

Tags: azure-sql-database, high-availability, failover

I  have a azure sql database in North Europe Region. It is almost 5 MB and it has Basic Pricing Tier. That database is not in Azure VM. I am using PaaS environment.
I configured Geo-Replication between North Europe and West Europe. When I tried to failover from West Europe to North Europe, it took 15 minutes. It is unacceptable, 15 minutes for 5 MB. Do you have any idea to reduce failover time?

Thank you

Comment: Azure SQL does not contain much in the way of tuning failover. At most you could open a ticket up with Azure support to see what is going on.

Comment: Did you create a `Azure Fail Over Group` for Azure SQL Paas servers? or did you activated Geo-replication feature for individual DBs?

Answer (score -1):

As `Igor Pagliai`(MSFT) Blog [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2014/07/03/deep-dive-sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups-and-cross-region-virtual-networks-in-azure/) of July 3, 2014 has as very well mention about
`Deep Dive: SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups and Cross-Region Virtual Networks in Azure`.

1. SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups Supported between Microsoft
   Azure Regions [Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2014/06/19/sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups-supported-between-microsoft-azure-regions/)
2. VNet-to-VNet: Connecting Virtual Networks in Azure across Different
       Regions [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vnet-to-vnet-connecting-virtual-networks-in-azure-across-different-regions/)
3. Configure AlwaysOn Availability Groups in Azure VM (GUI) [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-portal-sql-alwayson-availability-groups)
4. Configure an ILB listener for AlwaysOn Availability Groups in Azure [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-ps-sql-int-listener)

As per `Igor Pagliai` , `Azure Virtual Network Bandwidth and Latency is main factor in failover scenario`.

This is always my primary concern, even on-premise, When I have to build a multi-site AlwaysOn consideration: the connectivity between different datacenters will provide enough network bandwidth and low latency? Remember that we are in Azure and the connectivity between datacenters is provided by connecting two (at least) Virtual Networks using a VPN tunnel that comes with capacity limits, then let me recap some basic considerations:

- Today, for each Virtual Network, you can have only one VPN Gateway;
- Each VPN Gateway is able to provide, at the very maximum, a
  theoretical limit of 100Mbits/sec;
- If you connect a VPN Gateway to    multiple Virtual Networks,
  including on-premise local networks, each    channel will share the
  same theoretical bandwidth limit of    100Mbits/sec;
- VPN Gateway is backed up by two “hidden” Azure VMs of a    certain
  size in active-passive configuration, able to provide 99,90%
  availability SLA:

**Cloud Services, Virtual Machines and Virtual Network SLA**
[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sla)

**ExpressRoute or Virtual Network VPN – What’s right for me?**
Here

**NOTE:** In this blog post, I will not cover ExpressRoute, I didn’t test for AlwaysOn AG scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, I will read that references, but my database is not in Azure VM. 
I am using PaaS environment. Is that bad practise for geo-replication?

Comment: None of this applies to the OPs question.

Comment: What does OP mean? I did not understand.

Comment: @BanuAkks OP = Original Poster. Your question is around Azure SQL, this answer is dealing with Azure VMs that are running SQL Server...not the same nor is any of the info added relevant to your situation.